# SQL Search Query with Optional Field and different conditions

Tags: c#, .net, sql, visual-studio-2010

I have a search for in which the user can specify multiple search criteria. On some of the criteria field, they was choose whether they want to search on a specific value or a range. For example, the user can search on a field called "Week ending". The user can select whether the value for this field is a specific date, or whether is between two dates.

Each of the criteria fields are optional.

I'm struggling to find a way to create a SQL query to support something like this. The easiest way I can see possible is to have a load of different queries that support each different combinationm, but that is horrible and there must be a better solution.

I tried doing this using IFNULL and COALESC but the issue I ran into is how to deal with the optional presence of > and =.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you check what fields are completed and have a preformed SQL to handle each scenario?

Comment: Provide what some code

Comment: It is always better to provide some code to get good response!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using LINQ-To-SQL or LINQ-To-Entities you could build up your LINQ statement dynamically with each optional search field.

Alternatively, you could build up the SQL query string before passing that to the database. This is quite a dated approach though and you won't get compile time checking like LINQ. if you do go down this route be sure to use SQL parameters and not appending the search parameters to your query.

I'd really try to avoid duplicating any query code, adhere to the [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) principle and you'll save yourself a whole lot of maintenance pain later!